# How to validate type with validate.js

Tags: javascript, validation

What I would like to do is validate the type of object attributes

For example

```
var correctObject = {
    name : "John",
    age : 25
};

var constraints = {
    ...
};

validate(testObject, constraints);
//undefined test passes

var incorrectObject = {
    name : "John",
    age : "25"
};

validate(incorrectObject, constraints);
// age must be a string
```

Comment: Why not a simple loop with the `typeof` operator?

Comment: There are reasons to use validate.js which has benefit beyond type validation, such as value or pattern validation. Since Its useful for those reasons I'd like to use it to validate the type itself.